# Connected partition number of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, graph-minors

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. We say that a partition ${\cal P}$ of $V$ into non-empty subsets of $V$ is *connected* if any two distinct blocks are connected by an edge, or more formally, if for $p_1\neq p_2\in {\cal P}$ there is $e\in E$ with $$(p_1\cap e)\neq \varnothing\neq (p_2\cap e).$$ The maximum cardinality of any connected partition of $G$ is called the *connected partition number* $\text{cp}(G)$ of $G$.

The [Hadwiger number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_number) of a graph $G$, denoted by $\eta(G)$ is the maximum $n$ such that $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$. It is not hard to see that for any finite graph $G$, the number $\text{cp}(G)$ is greater or equal to both $\eta(G)$ and the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ of $G$. (As a side note, [Hadwiger's famous conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)) claims $\eta(G)\geq \chi(G)$ for any $G$.)

**Question.** Given a positive integer $k\geq 2$, is there an graph $G=(V,E)$ with $\text{cp}(G) \geq k\cdot\eta(G)$?

Comment: I think, we always have $\eta(G)\geqslant {\text cp} (G)$: for a connected partition, contract all edges inside every block.

Comment: @FedorPetrov if I understand the definition correctly, the path on 4 vertices $P_4$ has $cp(P_4) = 3$, using the set partition that puts the two leaves into a single block.

Comment: @MartinRubey ah, they need not be connected themselves. Agree. But then there exists even a tree with arbitrarily large $\text{cp}$: for any two blocks $P_i$, $P_j$ choose the vertices $A_{ij}\in P_i$ and $A_{ji}\in P_j$ and join them by an edge. We get many disjoint edges, but the graph is not yet connected. They may be connected by an extra path so that this is still a tree.

Comment: This is now http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001670/

Comment: Thanks @MartinRubey for your effort of putting this to findstat.org!

Comment: @FedorPetrov So a graph $G$ which contains a matching of size $\binom n2$ has $cp(G)\ge n$?

Comment: @bof sorry, I again forgot the definition. Yes, now I think this is true.

Comment: Yes, it should be $\text{cp}(G)$, will correct